How to stop the node js spawn processes?
I am trying to running a python script through node child processes. I want to run some cleanup functions in my python script when node sends the kill command.
Node js file
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

// Spawn the Python process
const pythonProcess = spawn("python", ["child.py"]);

pythonProcess.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

pythonProcess.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
  console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

pythonProcess.on("close", (code) => {
  console.log(`Python process exited with code ${code}`);
});

pythonProcess.on("error", (err) => {
  console.error("Failed to start Python process:", err);
});


setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Sending kill signal to Python process...");
  pythonProcess.kill("SIGTERM");
}, 5000); // Send kill signal after 5 seconds

Python file
import signal
import sys

def sigterm_handler(signum, frame):
    print("Received kill signal. Performing cleanup...")
    print("Cleanup complete. Exiting.")
    sys.exit(0)

# Register the signal handler for the kill signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sigterm_handler)


print("Python script is running...",flush=True)
while True:
    pass

Output:
$ node index.js
stdout: Python script is running...

Sending kill signal to Python process...
Python process exited with code null

Why it is not working ?
